# How to find a device on a network without an ip address

Tags: networking, ip-address

I am creating an application that runs on my home network on a dedicated device. I want to make the process of setting up the application easier for the user so that their phone can scan the network to find the ip-address of the device rather than having to figure out the IP and then configure it so.

TLDR: How to find a device on a network without an ip address? I also don't want to have to know a mac address or set a static ip address.

The idea is to be able to do something similar to what chromecast does to find it's device.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different mechanisms for this type of discovery, read on mDNS, UPnP, ...It depends on what you can put on the device and what you can add to your app on the phones. Chromecast currently uses mDNS, so do a lot of other devices.

Comment: The device on the network will simply be a linux box. What do you recommend I try to research?